# how to add current user uid to user collection when user signup in cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to add user id (which is unique generated by firestore) in userID field of users collection.

so for this i created this handle function

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password, fullname, username } = credentials
    try {
        await createUser({ email, password, fullname, username })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        setError(error.message)
    }

}
```

and this handle function calling createUser function from Authcontext

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState('')
const [refUser, setRefUser] = useState('')

console.log('checking on top ', user)
// Sign Up function 
const createUser = async ({ email, password, fullname, username }) => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

    // creatinguser collection
    const date = new Date().toISOString();
    const userRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        userId: '',
        username: username,
        email: email,
        name: fullname,
        followers: [],
        followings: [],
        posts: [],
        date: date
    });
    
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", `${userRef?.id}`), {
        userId: "user?.uid"
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentUser) => {
        setUser(currentUser);
    return () => {
        unsubscribe();
    };
});

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, refUser }}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
```

}

so please let me know how to updateDoc only that time when user create new account/ signup so that i can store there uid in userID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#createuserwithemailandpassword) function returns an instance of [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredential_interface). You can read UID of new user as shown below:

```
const createUser = async ({ email, password, fullname, username }) => {
  const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  const userId = user.uid; 
 
  // Add document in user collection
  const userRef = await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userId), {
    email,
    userId,
    username,
    name: fullname,
    followers: [],
    followings: [],
    posts: [],
    date: new Date().toISOString() // <-- or new Date(); for Timestamp field
  }); 
}
```

You can use the userId as the document ID as it makes it easier to get user's document later using `getDoc()` instead of running a query to find a document.